# Proper implementation of DbOperations in Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my android application, I have various "entities" such as user defined. I'm using a single DbOperations class that has the default `Select`, `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` functionality.

An async task is used as an intermediary. It sits in between my entities and DbOperations class and performs everything asynchronously. Here's an example.

**ASYNC CLASS - with Insert Method code**

```
private DbResponse InsertUser() {       
    ContentValues cntValues = GetCrmUserContentVal();
    long result = _dbConn.InsertRecord(cntValues, TABLE_NAME);
    DbResponse dbResponse = new DbResponse();
    if(result == -1)
    {
        dbResponse.setStatus(false);        
    }
    else {
        dbResponse.setStatus(true);
        dbResponse.setID(result);
    }
    return dbResponse;

}
```

**CRM USER Entity Class - Insert Method**

```
public void InsertintoDb()
    {
        new CRMUserDbOperations(this,this,DbOperationType.Insert,getCurrentContext()).execute();
    }
```

**DbResponse - Return type class** is a seperate class -

```
private Boolean Status;
private String ErrorMessage;
private Cursor Data;
private long ID;
private DbOperationType dbOpType;
```

In the **doBackground** process of the async task, I have this switch code -

```
switch (_DbOpType) { // Enum type.
            case Insert:
                dbResponse = InsertUser();
                break;
            case Select:
                dbResponse = SelectUser();
                break;
            case Update:
                dbResponse = UpdateUser();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidParameterException(
                        _Context.getString(R.string.invalid_io));
        }
```

As you can notice this asynchronous task has code for all the various operations I might have to perform on the entity. For other entities, I'll have the same structure as well...

Now my question is, could I be doing this in a better manner?

Comment: This may be of use to you https://bitbucket.org/FabianCCook/dbhelper in the future. I am just getting into entities now

Comment: @FabianCook, that link is very informative, thanks!

Comment: The base part of it is done, the documentation explains how to use it etc. The entity part of it is being build on top of it.

Comment: @FabianCook, Would it be possible for you to host it on GitHub?

Comment: Already is, hold up, will get you the link

Comment: https://github.com/FabianCook/AndroidDbHelper

Would this answer your question? As I will answer it with this if you wish.

Comment: @FabianCook, Please wait a few days. If there are no other answers, post yours as an answer.

Comment: No problem :). Let me know how you get on with the library, need any help just email me, email address is on my profile.

Comment: Also: http://fabiancook.github.io/AndroidDbHelper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done in a better way. Let me give you an example of how we are handling it in our current app. You just need 4 `AsyncTask`s in total for insert, update, delete and select operations. Let me give you an example.

You have an interface and every entity will implement it:

```
public interface DbOps {

    public int delete(String where);

    public void insert();

    public void update();

    public Cursor select();
}
```

**NOTE:** Arguments and return types will be of your choice that fits your need but must also fit for every entity class. I am going to use `delete()` method as an example.

Now you need only one `DeleteTask` for all entitites:

```
private static class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private final DbOps mOps; 

    public RowDeleteTask(DbOps ops) {
        mOps = ops; 
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... wheres) {
        String where = wheres[0];
        int rowsDeleted = mOps.delete(where);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }
}
```

Fire it like this:

```
new DeleteTask(mUserEntity).execute("id = 4");
new DeleteTask(mMoviesEntity).execute("name = x-man");
```

and obviously you will have something similar to this if we take `UserEntitiy` for example:

```
public UserEntity implements DbOps{

    @Override
    public int delete(String where){
       return _dbConn.delete(mTable, where, null);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: You should actually just use one for all four, in most versions of android it is only going to run one at a time anyway, why create unnecessary objects?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't product placement or anything, it is open source, I have been working on Async databases for a while now, and have recently created a library for it.

It is hosted on Github at http://fabiancook.github.io/AndroidDbHelper/

It covers a more general need for async database usage, you can either do one thing async if you want, or the whole lot.

It will have an implementation for a entity framework in the coming months as I am working on a Ubuntu touch version at this moment.

Any info needed just ask.

For small amounts of objects entities are great, but when you want to report on them they get really slow, which is even apparent in microsofts entity framework. For the most it is usually a heck of a lot faster (performance wise) to use straight SQL in an async way as it takes out the need for that middle object.

Note, between android 1.6 and 3.0 the `AsyncTask` class would execute sometimes in parallel, which would cause some problems in any database. So when using those versions you there would have to some differences, this is being worked into my DbHelper :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)

Comment: For the question at hand, the structure suggested by @M-WaJeEh is more apt. But thanks. I'll keep following your library.