# Android app data storage design

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an Android app for homework management. I'm a senior in college, so my experience on larger projects is very limited, but I'd like to design all parts of this app well instead of just throwing something together. This includes the way data is stored.

We have two main objects/entities: `Task` and `Subject`. Even if someone uses the app for the whole time they're in college and never deletes anything, I'm guessing there would be a maximum of a few thousand tasks and a couple hundred subjects (not all subjects would be shown at once). The initial version of the app won't sync data with a server, but this is a definite possibility in the future, so I'd like to design with that in mind. We might also have an option for users to send tasks to each other.

Here are my questions:

1. Would a SQLite database be the best option for storing the amount of data we're likely to have, or would something like serializing it to XML or JSON then loading it into memory when the app starts work?
2. I'm used to thinking in terms of objects. This means that if I use a database and it has a Task table and a Subject table, my first instinct is to convert each database table row into a corresponding object for viewing/editing. (The objects' setters would contain validation logic.) Is this a good/helpful/necessary way to think? If not, what is the alternative?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I recently asked a question somewhat related to this, and got a few good responses. Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649395/proper-implementation-of-dboperations-in-async-task

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future (especially related to question 2), you might want to look into object-relational mapping frameworks, which handle the conversion between objects and tables automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is broad so may comments below may not be 100% correct as I don't have all the information about your system.

1. SQLite is better suited for storing thousands of records than files (be it JSON or XML). This is especially true if your data is not static, i.e. will be changed during the usage of your app (which is the case for you, I believe). You can take advantage of existing functionality for records inserts, updates, deletions, using indexes, etc.
2. Yes, you generally create objects similar to your database. But you don't usually need to convert each and every record from the database into your objects. You usually query the database for a limited number of objects, depending on what you want to show in the UI. Of course, if you need to show all, let's say, tasks, you need to get them all.

Comment: Thanks! So do you think that when creating or editing a task, it would make sense to convert the task's database record to an object, use the object's setters to make and validate changes, and then write the information back to the database once editing is done?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Would a SQLite database be the best option for storing the amount of data we're likely to have, or would something like serializing it to XML or JSON then loading it into memory when the app starts work?**

Yes SQlite will be the option for you.It will give you a structured format and in future if you want to access data from remote end the same structure of tables can be used without much change in the code.

**2. I'm used to thinking in terms of objects. This means that if I use a database and it has a Task table and a Subject table, my first instinct is to convert each database table row into a corresponding object for viewing/editing. (The objects' setters would contain validation logic.) Is this a good/helpful/necessary way to think? If not, what is the alternative?**

you can simply execute queries to manipulate data.
But dont forget to encryt your database if you storing it in mobile itself.